# Android Studio don't recognize my device

Tags: android, android-studio

My device is a Sony Xperia Z3 and I used to test my apps on it and it suddently stopped recognizing.

I already tried to change the cable, made sure the file transfer method is MTP and killed adb with no results

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: On Developer options (device) you activated 'enable USB debugging'?

Comment: I remember I had a similar situation on older version of android studio. After I killed the adb you need to restart android studio in order to restart adb connection. This issue was fixed on newer versions of android studio

Comment: It could be that your USB drivers messed up. Here is more information: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: I reinstalled the driver and it worked again
I'd already forgotten about it
Thank you